# JSON schema for an object whose value is an array of objects

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I am writing a software that can read the JSON data from a file. The file contains "person" - an object whose value is an array of objects. I am planning to use a JSON schema validating libraries to validate the contents instead of writing the code myself. What is the correct schema that conforms to JSON Schema Draf-4 which represents the below data?

```
{
   "person" : [
      {
         "name" : "aaa",
         "age"  : 10
      },
      {
         "name" : "ddd",
         "age"  : 11
      },
      {
         "name" : "ccc",
         "age"  : 12
      }
   ]
}
```

The schema that wrote down is given below. I am not sure whether it is correct or is there any other form?

```
{
   "person" : {
      "type" : "object",
      "properties" : {
         "type" : "array",
         "items" : {
            "type" : "object",
            "properties" : {
               "name" : {"type" : "string"},
               "age" : {"type" : "integer"}
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually only have one line in the wrong place, but that one line breaks the whole schema.  "person" is a property of the object and thus must be under the `properties` keyword.  By putting "person" at the top,  JSON Schema interprets it as a keyword instead of a property name.  Since there is no `person` keyword, JSON Schema ignores it and everything below it.  Therefore, it is the same as validating against the empty schema `{}` which places no restrictions on what a JSON document can contain.  Any valid JSON is valid against the empty schema.

```
{
   "type" : "object",
   "properties" : {
      "person" : {
         "type" : "array",
         "items": {
            "type" : "object",
            "properties" : {
               "name" : {"type" : "string"}
               "age" : {"type" : "integer"}
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

By the way, there are several online JSON Schema testing tools out there that can help you out when crafting your schemas.  This one is my goto http://jsonschemalint.com/draft4/#

Also, here is a great JSON Schema reference that might help you out as well: https://spacetelescope.github.io/understanding-json-schema/